# Using Kotlin in Android library distributed as AAR

Tags: android, kotlin, aar

Is it even possible to use Kotlin to write a library?

The problem I see is that it will depend on specyfic versions of `kotlin-stdlib` and `kotlin-runtime` and force user of the library to use the same version.

I'm considering using `jarjar` to repackage those but then, how to include those in a fatjar-type distribution? Inside the unpacked aar I see `/libs` directory - is there a way to use that?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40859766/how-does-android-merge-the-custom-librarys-support-library-with-that-of-applica/40860398#40860398) to understand better how gradle builds the applications. The same depicts plugins on the classpath. I suggest not to build `fatJar` when distributing libraries, this will cause problems with versions.

Comment: There are Kotlin-based libraries in the Android Arsenal, so presumably it is possible. I haven't played much with Kotlin personally, and so I do not know how they do it. But unless `kotlin-stdlib` and `kotlin-runtime` are very small, your library may get rather large if you embed them. `libs/` in an AAR are for native libraries (`.so` files) IIRC.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Looks like the existing libraries just include the dependency: `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlinVersion"`

Comment: @R.Zagórski: I understand your recomendation, that's why I'm looking into changing the package names.

Comment: @atok : Why don't you write your comment as an answer. It works. It will be helpful

Answer (score 6):

As per the comments, there are several `.aar` libraries available that are written in Kotlin such as [MapMe](https://github.com/TradeMe/MapMe).

Indeed there is a curated list of such libraries in [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/awesome-kotlin)

You can see by examining the `build.gradle` for the same that these do include a dependency on `kotlin-stdlib`.

This is not a lightweight dependency: the `.jar` size is approx 1MB. And if you make a blank project, compile the `.apk`, and upload it to a [method count site](http://inloop.github.io/apk-method-count/) it comes to `6086` methods.

However, if the consuming project already uses Kotlin they will already have bourne the burden of the extra classes. Since they will have explicitly included `kotlin-stdlib` as a dependency in their `build.gradle` it will probably force resolution of the dependency in your library to their version. This is unlikely to cause problems with `stdlib`.

Even if the consumer is not using Kotlin in their project, aggressive use of Proguard can eliminate unused methods. The [official Kotlin website explains](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/android-overview.html#using-kotlin-for-android-development):

> Footprint: Kotlin has a very compact runtime library, which can be further reduced through the use of ProGuard. In a real application, the Kotlin runtime adds only a few hundred methods and less than 100K to the size of the .apk file.

The source for the second statement is a [blog post on Medium](https://blog.gouline.net/kotlin-production-tales-62b56057dc8a) so your mileage may vary.